# bash xargs: same command gives different output

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, xargs

When I run

```
ls -1 *.a | xargs -I{} echo {} | sed 's/.a//'
```

The output is

```
1
2
3
```

When I run

```
ls -1 *.a | xargs -I{} bash -c "echo {} $(echo {} | sed 's/.a//')"
```

and the output is

```
1.a 1.a
2.a 2.a
3.a 3.a
```

What is the reason for this anomaly?

Comment: I suppose the shell is executing before `$(echo {} | sed 's/.a//')` that answers with `{}`. Then you have `bash -c "echo {} {}" ` on which acts `xargs -I{}` substituting at the `{}` the output of `ls *.a`. Ps> You do not need `-1` when you pipe `ls`, _somehow he_ knows to be piped and it is automatic.

Comment: Hastur is right. Run `bash -xc 'ls *.a | xargs -I{} bash -c "echo {} $(echo {} | sed s/.a//)"'` and you will see.

Comment: @guest Thx, I was writing the same... :-) but with too many words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your in your directory the presence of the files `1.a`,`2.a`,`3.a`.

With the command

```
ls *.a | xargs -I{} echo {} | sed 's/.a//'
```

you have no subshells, the output of `ls` is piped in `xargs` that make its substitutions. Then the output is piped to `sed`. From here your first result.

With the command

```
ls *.a | xargs -I{} bash -c "echo {} $(echo {} | sed 's/.a//')"
```

you have a new element `$(echo {} | sed 's/.a//')`.

It is expanded and becomes

```
echo {}                # -- > {}
echo {} | sed 's/.a//' # -- > {}  again the same.
```

so your command can be *rewritten* as

```
 ls *.a | xargs -I{} bash -c "echo {} {} "
```

that gives your second output.

As just now said also [guest](https://superuser.com/users/247996/guest) in his comment debug your *script* <sup>[[1](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html#sect_02_03_02)]</sup> (or command); with `set -x` you enable the debug in the current shell or script and with `set +x` you disable it:

```
set -x    
ls *.a | xargs -I{} bash -c "echo {} $(echo {} | sed 's/.a//')"
set +x
```

and you will see each step

```
+ ls --color=auto 1.a 2.a 3.a
++ echo '{}'
++ sed s/.a//
+ xargs '-I{}' bash -c 'echo {} {}'
1.a 1.a
2.a 2.a
3.a 3.a
```

Comment: Is there any workaround?

Comment: What's the output you want to have? What was your idea?

Comment: debug trace mismatch >_<

Comment: @stas `ls *.a | xargs -I{} bash -c "echo {} \$(echo {} | sed 's/.a//')"`

Comment: @guest `>_< `  Thanks, I copied from the other command ... I was distracted by a _querelle_ on another [question](http://superuser.com/q/1093111/257269)...